# How can I initiate/respond a Hangout from a remote device?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, google-hangouts

The scenario is 3 computers with hangout and 2 users:

1. **User 1**:

   1.1 Computer A (controller) is the one that will manage the calls (has
   keyword, mouse but not webcam and mic),

   1.2 Computer B is where the hangout of user 1 will be displayed (has webcam and mic      but not keyword and mouse)
2. **User 2**

   2.1 Computer C is where the user 2 will interact. This is a normal pc and has webcam, mic, keyword and mouse.

The goal is to initiate or respond a hangout from the user 1 using the controller. How could I start?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if is what you are asking for when you say hangout if talking about Google hangouts or WebRTC...

If using WebRTC, start a remote PeerConnection is ok and just need some signalling, but you have to accept media permissions, so if you are using a browser the user needs to explicitly give permissions to media sources (at least one time if over HTTPS). If you are not in a browser its up to your app

Comment: I'm talking about Google Hangout.